# Mongodb buscar elemento padre con al menos varios hijos contenidos en un array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Supongamos que tengo una colección de usuarios:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: {
        first: 'John',
        last: 'Backus'
    },
    birth: new Date('Dec 03, 1924'),
    death: new Date('Mar 17, 2007'),
    contribs: ['Fortran', 'ALGOL', 'Backus-Naur Form', 'FP'],
    awards: [
        {
            award: 'National Medal',
            year: 1975,
            by: 'NSF'
        },
        {
            award: 'Turing Award',
            year: 1977,
            by: 'ACM'
        }
    ]
}
```

// y bastantes más objetos de usuarios

Quiero encontrar aquellas personas que han ganado como mínimo los premios: **['National Medal', 'Turing Award']** aunque hayan ganado alguno más.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes utilizar la notación de punto para acceder a los elementos de la matriz, encerrándolo entre comillas. Luego, usa el operador query `$all` ‎que coincide con los valores especificados en una matriz.‎

La consulta te quedaría así:

```
db.users.find({"awards.award": {$all: ['National Medal', 'Turing Award']}})
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Wilson, pero usando el operador $in, me devolvería cualquier resultado con una de las coincidencias, yo necesito que me devuelva aquellos resultados que tengan las 2 coincidencias como mínimo.

Comment: Tenes razón, no comprendí bien. En ese caso habría que cambiar el operador por $all. Espero mi respuesta te haya guiado

Answer (score 0):

Vale, he encontrado la forma correcta de hacerlo.

Para ello hay que utilizar el operador `$all`, que hace que tengan que coincidir al menos los 2 valores.

La consulta quedaría así:

```
db.users.find({"awards.award": {$all: ['National Medal', 'Turing Award']}})
```